# How to reconnect with SVN repository from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, collabnet, svn-repository

I installed CollabNet Subversion Server on my server and had been using it with Eclipse on my desktop for a long time.  Through some Eclipse changes, my SVN client install was lost (the server was untouched).  After re-installation of the SVN client plug-in, I am unable to re-connect my projects with the SVN repository; I don't know the URL or anything.

When I open "SVN Repository Browser" in Eclipse, right click and select New > Repository Location, It asks me for a URL.  I have typed "file://machineName" and "http://machineName", then the Browse... button, but I get "`An error occurred while accessing the repository entry`".  Since the server hasn't changed, and I see that svnserve.exe is listening on 3690, and httpd.exe on port 90, I presume there's more needed on the URL, but I don't know what that is.

Resources available to use to recover the connection to the repository:

- The .svn file in the project folder
- The files on the server supporting the repository
- svn.exe on the server (it says `'.' is not a working copy` when I tried a few commands).  I don't have svn.exe on the client machine.

Where should I look to see how to reconnect my projects with the CollabNet svn server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the expected Eclipse SVN plugin is being used (subversive vs subclipse, etc).
2. Try connecting with `svn://`

Answer (score 0):

**collabnet** has its own plug-in try to install them from **eclipse marketplace**  in Help menu.

Check the repository name it should be

```
"http:// [Your_Machine_name] / svn / [Your_Repository_name]"
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: what exactly do you need help with?